# How to abort room when there is no opponent player available in Google Play Games?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games, multiplayer, 2d-games

I am creating a Multiplayer Game in Unity.

To create a room, I am using:

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.CreateQuickGame(MinOpponents, MaxOpponents, GameVariant, listener);
```

To get progress of room creation, I am using:

```
public void OnRoomSetupProgress(float progress) {
}
```

The above function, however, is just called once at `progress = 20` and then, never again if there are no other players available.

Since initially, I won't have a lot of players using this app, I want to wait for 10 seconds to connect to any other player and if there are no players, I want to start the game with built in AI. For this, I need to abort the current room setup progress in a clean way. I don't know how can I move further.

Please let me know if you know solution for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to Multiplayer Game in Unity, this [GitHub post](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/RTMP.md) only discussed about leaving the room when the game finishes using `PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.LeaveRoom();` to  trigger a call to your listener's `OnLeftRoom`.

You may want to try [Adding Real-time Multiplayer Support to Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer) specifically [Adding a waiting room UI](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer#optional_adding_a_waiting_room_ui) which states that

> If you use the waiting room UI, you do not need to implement additional logic to decide when the game should be started or canceled, as seen earlier in `shouldStartGame()` and `shouldCancelGame()`. When you obtain an `Activity.RESULT_OK` result, you can start right away since the required number of participants have been connected. Likewise, when you get an error result from the waiting room UI, you can simply leave the room.

To leave the room, call `leave()`:

```
// leave room
Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(mGoogleApiClient, null, mRoomId);

// remove the flag that keeps the screen on
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```